# Passing through variable on ng-compile returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
var suggestionElement = document.createElement('div');

vm.suggestActivate = function(keyCode) {
  if(keyCode === 32) {
    if(vm.summaryData) {
      var words = vm.words;
      var suggestions = "<div></div>";

      var targetElement = event.srcElement;
      var targetElementModel = targetElement.getAttribute("ng-model");

      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $log.debug(targetElementModel);
        suggestions += '<div ng-click="vm.appendSuggestion(targetElementModel)" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor=\'#D8D8D8\'" onMouseLeave="this.style.backgroundColor=\'#F3F3F3\'">' + words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)] + '</div>';
      }

      suggestionElement.innerHTML = suggestions;
      suggestionElement.setAttribute('style', 'background: #F3F3F3; position: relative; top: -3.9em; width: 25%');
      suggestionElement.style.display = 'block';

      angular.element(targetElement.parentNode).append($compile(suggestionElement)($scope));
    }
  }
  else {
    suggestionElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

vm.appendSuggestion = function(model) {
  $log.debug(model);
}
```

In the above segment of code in the `vm.appendSuggestion` method, why is `model` returned as undefined? If I log it during the for loop, it returns a value? I want to return a value in the `vm.appendSuggestion` method as well. However, I noticed when it is hardcoded, it does not return as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the `div` element to which you have assigned the ngClick directive, Angular tries to find `targetElementModel` on the `$scope` and it does not exist there. You cannot pass a value to it like that.

A solution might be to expose a list of target elements to the view and do something like `'<div ng-click="vm.appendSuggestion(' + targetElementIndex + ')" ...`. But this is just an example - you might find a more appropriate solution for your problem.